# How do I say if value exists display value otherwise leave well enough alone with simple_form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using simple_form and I only want the `value: @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") %>` to execute if @image.start_at has a value.

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

For example, this is from my image create/update _form and this works seemingly exactly how I want it to if I already have an image that has a start_at value. However, when I am creating a new image and there is no start_at value yet how can I say don't try to put this value in the input? I'm not interested in having a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at? ? @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") : nil %>
```

based on @luissimo 's answer

Comment: **`value: @image.start_at.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")`**

Comment: it's more elegant

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like this?

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") if @image.start_at.present? %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

which puts an if statement inline with value

Answer (score 0):

Check for blank and assign a value appropriately:

```
<%  @image.start_at.blank? ? starts_at = nil : starts_at = @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")  %>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: starts_at %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This removed the entire input box.

Comment: Try the updated version.  Basically it will just change the value used depending on what you have.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this:**

*Using a unless statement*

```
<%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") unless @image.start_at.nil? %>
```

*Using an if statement*

```
<%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") if @image.start_at.present? %>
```

*Using an if / else statement*

```
<%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at.nil? ? @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") : 'no value'  %>
```

Comment: The first two removed the text input box an the third threw and error..this one: `undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So I adapted your last one example, instead of checking for true nil? I checked for true not nil and instead of having leaving 'no value' i put nil. `<%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control', value: @image.start_at? ? @image.start_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") : nil %>`